# Retrieving SQL data in to HTML from XAMPP PHPmyadmin

Tags: php, html, sql, google-chrome-extension, xampp

I am building an extension, I just want to retrieve data from my SQL table stored in localhost (PHPmyadmin XAMPP).
I have the table with only two value and a single row.

I want to fetch name and ip from the only row in to my HTML file of my chrome extension.
Eg:

```
 _______________________
 |id | name | ip         |
 ------------------------
 | 1 | fb   | 192.134.23 |   
 ------------------------ 


   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
    <title>Hello World</title>

    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min">
    </script>

    <script src="popup.js">
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>


    <form action="http://localhost/data.php" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" id="lol" name="lol" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" id="card" name="card" value="" />   
                   First Name: <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="Submit">
    </form>


   <form action="http://localhost/retrieve.php" method="post"> //(THIS IS 
    THE FORM I M USING TO CONNECT TO MY PHP SCRIPT.)

        <input type="hidden" id="lol2" name="lol2" value="" /> 
        <input type="hidden" id="card2" name="card2" value="" />   

        <input type="Submit">
    </form>

  </body>
  </html>


 <?php

 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "uppercase");

   /* check connection */
   if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
   exit();
  }

  $query = "SELECT name, ip FROM urltable ;
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);

  /* associative and numeric array */
  $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
     lol2= $row[0];
      card2= $row["name"];

  /* free result set */
  $result->free();

  /* close connection */
  $mysqli->close();
  ?>
```

I want to store the value of (name and ip) in variable "lol2" and "card2".
This is what I tried
I am not getting how to store a value from a php script into an HTML 
variable.
(i.e accessing an HTML variable in a php file)

Comment: you are missing the $ in front of the variables.

Comment: an HTML variable ? since when HTML does have variable ? i assume you meant javascript right ?

Comment: Do you mean POST/GET variables? The values for those fields will be in $_POST['lol2'] and $_POST['card2']

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
$sql = "select * from urltable";
            $result=$mysqli->prepare($sql);
             $result->execute();
             $result_0=$result->get_result();
             while($row=$result_0->fetch_assoc(){ 
$lol2=$row['ip'];
$card2=$row['name'];
}
```

So you can go ahead and print it in your HTML like this

```
<?php echo $lol2; ?>
 <?php echo $card2; ?>
```

Comment: how can I print php data in my html file?

Comment: I have already provided. The last two lines of code. That is how to print in HTML. using **echo**